# Like operator and Trailing spaces in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-like, ntext

This one matches `column_name like 'CharEndsHere%'`

and

This one doesn't `column_name like 'CharEndsHere'`

I know that like operator will consider even the trailing spaces, so I just copied the **exact column value** (with trailing spaces) and pasted it.

Something like `column_name like 'CharEndsHere  '` yet it doesn't match -- **why?**.

I haven't used `'='` operator since the columns type is `ntext`

Is there something I am missing here or shouldn't I use `like` operator in this way?

Edited : `column_name like 'CharEndsHere__'` (__ denoted the spaces) `'CharEndsHere  '` is the exact value in that cell, using `like` in this way valid or no?

Edit :

This is the code I tried,

```
SELECT * 
FROM [DBName].[dbo].[TableName] 
WHERE [DBName].[dbo].[TableName].Address1 LIKE rtrim('4379 Susquehanna Trail S  ')
```

I have also tried without using `rtrim`, yet the same result

Edit: According to Blindy's answer,

```
If a comparison in a query is to return all rows with the string LIKE 'abc' (abc
without a space), all rows that start with abc and have zero or more trailing 
blanks are returned.
```

But in my case, I have queried, `Like 'abc'` and there is a cell containing `'abc '(with trailing spaces)` which is not returned. That's my actual problem

Comment: LIKE without any wildcards (% or _) will work exactly like the = operator!

Comment: @Mithrandir Yes I mentioned in the question too. But what im looking for here is like 'char__' to match without using %

Comment: Then you should state that in your question! You want to use the like operator in a way it can't be used. Keep wanting it, it won't change the way like works!

Comment: @Mithrandir Yes as u said, but i just want to know will it work or no. i had edited my question.

Comment: `LIKE` is fine - but you should **stop using** the `NTEXT` datatype! Use `NVARCHAR(MAX)` instead. `NTEXT` was crappy and many string functions don't work at all on it. Use `NVARCHAR(MAX)` for all your extra-long Unicode strings and you'll be fine!

Comment: `ntext`, `text`, and `image` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)`, `varchar(max)`, and `varbinary(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a case of reading the documentation, it's very explicitly stated here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx

> When you perform string comparisons by using LIKE, all characters in the pattern string are significant. This includes leading or trailing spaces. If a comparison in a query is to return all rows with a string LIKE 'abc ' (abc followed by a single space), a row in which the value of that column is abc (abc without a space) is not returned. However, trailing blanks, in the expression to which the pattern is matched, are ignored. If a comparison in a query is to return all rows with the string LIKE 'abc' (abc without a space), all rows that start with abc and have zero or more trailing blanks are returned.

Edit: According to your comments, you seem to be looking for a way to use `like` while ignoring trailing spaces. Use something like this: `field like rtrim('abc   ')`. It will still use indexes because `rtrim()` is a scalar operand and it's evaluated before the lookup phase.

Comment: This makes sense. Out of curiosity, what does this mean `The only exception to this rule is the LIKE predicate. When the right side of a LIKE predicate expression features a value with a trailing space, SQL Server does not pad the two values to the same length before the comparison occurs.` which can be found here: [How SQL Server Compares Strings with Trailing Spaces](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316626)

Comment: The latter is how `=` works, it pads both sides to the same length, then compares (effectively ignoring trailing spaces on both sides). That's saying `like` doesn't do any padding, so the pattern side trailing spaces are significant (while it still drops the test value side spaces).

Comment: So is that mean i can use like 'value__' (__ means the spaces) to get to match the value.

Comment: @Vignesh, that's kind of an ambiguous statement. If you want the spaces to be significant, just use a plain `like`. If you want them *not* to be significant, pass the pattern through `rtrim()` first.

Comment: @Blindy the spaces are significant, but even using the plain like doesn't match, thats the real reason i asked this question here.

Comment: @Vignesh, Then post some code that shows the problem. I've tested it in 2005, 2008 and 2012, they both work as explained. Here's a small sample: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/20677

Comment: @Blindy I have edited my question, and also the rtrim also doesn't work

Comment: Yet as you can see from the fiddle I linked, it works. At this point I'd take a hard look at your code (can't do that for you since you still won't post code I can run and see fail, one select on a table I don't know doesn't help).

Comment: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=62621 - this link portraits this as a bug, but not sure of it

Comment: This isn't a MySql question.

Comment: @Blindy Yes i certainly agrre with you. But i just denoted that i may also occur in sqlserver